# how to fetch data from 3 table in php which have two cloum common

Tags: sql, join

[image]

I have three table in which `user id` and `country_code` are common.

In table1 I have one entry with `user_id=2` and `country_code=IN`
As you see in image.

I want to show all data from those three tables  where `user_id=2` and `country_code` are come from all table with there `user_id` as I have shown in the image.

I use this query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT user_visit.country_code
 FROM  user_born INNER JOIN user_visit ON user_visit.user_information_id =
 user_born.user_information_id 
 INNER JOIN user_live ON user_live.user_information_id
 WHERE user_born.user_information_id=2
 ORDER BY user_born.user_information_id
```

but it only shows user_visit data

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a JOIN, you need a UNION query. UNION query just appends the data together.

```
SELECT user_id, country_code
FROM table1

UNION ALL 

SELECT user_id, country_code
FROM table2

UNION ALL

SELECT user_id, country_code
FROM table3
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to combine data in all table you should look at `UNION` rather than a `JOIN`

A UNION will combine result of multiple queries, example

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY_CODE FROM 
(
  SELECT USER_INFORMATION_ID, COUNTRY_CODE 
   FROM USER_BORN 
   WHERE    USER_INFORMATION_ID = ?
 UNION
  SELECT USER_INFORMATION_ID, COUNTRY_CODE 
   FROM USER_VISIT 
   WHERE USER_INFORMATION_ID = ?
 UNION
  SELECT USER_INFORMATION_ID, COUNTRY_CODE 
   FROM USER_LIVE  
   WHERE USER_INFORMATION_ID = ?
)
```

The `?` indicate bind variable where you supply user information id. Since you need distinct list of countries, I've added DISTINCT keyword as well.

Answer (score 0):

'Combine' as in logical `OR` ("user_id and country_code can be from table1 or table2 or table3")?:

```
SELECT user_id, country_code FROM table1
UNION
SELECT user_id, country_code FROM table2
UNION
SELECT user_id, country_code FROM table3;
```

Comment: thank for your code, i also try and get result those i expected.  thank again        i try this and get result :-                                                                                                                                                                                              SELECT country_code ,continent_name from user_visit where user_information_id=2  UNION SELECT country_code,continent_name from user_live where user_information_id=2 UNION SELECT country_code ,continent_name from user_born where user_information_id=2 ORDER BY country_code